# JUnit 5 TestTemplates and Extensions: Accessing TestTemplateInvocationContext?

Tags: java, junit5

Use case:

- A test shall be executed with different parameters.
- For this test we want to use an extension doing some pre-/postprocessing. This step needs access to the current set parameter.

Initially I tried implementing this with a `@ParameterizedTest`. Here the extension has no chance to access the parameter (The parameter is evaluated *after* the `beforeTestExecution` call). As a matter of this I used `@TemplateTest` with `TestTemplateInvocationContextProvider` (as described in the [guide](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-test-templates)). Now I could see my parameters in the `extensionContext`. Unfortunately there are accessor methods missing for that:

- on `MethodExtensionContext` (resp. super class): `getTestDescriptor() : TestTemplateInvocationTestDescriptor`
- on `TestTemplateInvocationTestDescriptor`: `getInvocationContext()`

As a hopefully temporary workaround I do some reflection to access my `invocationContext`.
Is there something that tells against introducing these accessor methods? Is there even a better / simpler way for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can provide additional Extensions in the `TestTemplateInvocationContext`. The following is based on the example in the user guide:

```
@TestTemplate
@ExtendWith(MyTestTemplateInvocationContextProvider.class)
void testTemplate(String parameter) {
    System.out.println("Test with parameter: " + parameter);
    assertEquals(3, parameter.length());
}

static class MyTestTemplateInvocationContextProvider implements TestTemplateInvocationContextProvider {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsTestTemplate(ExtensionContext context) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<TestTemplateInvocationContext> provideTestTemplateInvocationContexts(ExtensionContext context) {
        return Stream.of(invocationContext("foo"), invocationContext("bar"));
    }

    private TestTemplateInvocationContext invocationContext(String parameter) {
        return new TestTemplateInvocationContext() {
            @Override
            public String getDisplayName(int invocationIndex) {
                return parameter;
            }

            @Override
            public List<Extension> getAdditionalExtensions() {
                return Arrays.asList(parameterResolver(), preProcessor(), postProcessor());
            }

            private BeforeTestExecutionCallback preProcessor() {
                return new BeforeTestExecutionCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Pre-process parameter: " + parameter);
                    }
                };
            }

            private AfterTestExecutionCallback postProcessor() {
                return new AfterTestExecutionCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Post-process parameter: " + parameter);
                    }

               };
            }

            private ParameterResolver parameterResolver() {
                return new ParameterResolver() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean supportsParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
                        return parameterContext.getParameter()
                                .getType()
                                .equals(String.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
                        return parameter;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The console output is:

```
Pre-process parameter: foo
Test with parameter: foo
Post-process parameter: foo
Pre-process parameter: bar
Test with parameter: bar
Post-process parameter: bar
```

Answer (score 0):

This would mean that I have to one extension to the other. Currently I have two extensions: One (`MyProvider`) implementing `TestTemplateInvocationContextProvider` (used for test parametrization) and one (`MyCallback`) implementing `BeforeTestExecutionCallback` for doing some preparation work.

This looks like:

```
  @ExtendWith(MyCallback.class)
  public class WebTest {
    @TestTemplate
    @ExtendWith(MyProvider.class)
    public void showPage() throws Exception {
    }
  }
```

My goal would be getting the current parameter in the class level extension:

```
  public class MyCallback implements BeforeAllCallback, BeforeTestExecutionCallback {
  public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext ctx) {
  }
  public void beforeTestExecution(ExtensionContext ctx) {
    // HERE I WANT CURRENT PARAMETER VALUE:
    ((TestTemplateInvocationTestDescriptor) ((MethodExtensionContext) ctx).testDescriptor).invocationContext;
  }
```

If I had two public methods added (as mentioned in first edit) it would be possible but maybe it is against the concept?

Comment: I now split up MyCallback and moved the `BeforeTestExecutionCallback` part into a new extension which I added to `getAdditionalExtensions` (as suggested).